# How to register more views with one region in popup window?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a menu with menu items. Some of them should show content in one popup window. Every menu item belongs to a module with a view. In this popup window, I have one region, in which I want to show views. In my case, the first menu item shows "FormVerionsView", the second menu item show "Publish" view in "PopupContentRegion". Problem is when I click on any of these two menu items, the popup window is empty and none of the views are shown.

I use the .NET framework 4.6.1, Prism 7.2.0.1367.

I've tried this solution:

Here is a part of my App.xaml.cs file

```
protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainWindow>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<DefaultPopup>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
    }
```

Here is part of my DefaultPopup.xaml file

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static regNames:RegionNames.PopupContentRegion}"></ContentControl>
```

I have 2 modules with one view in each module. Here is part of FormVerions module

```
public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        var popupRegion = new SingleActiveRegion();
        popupRegion.Add(typeof(FormVersionsView), "FormVersionsView");
        _regionManager.Regions.Add(RegionNames.PopupContentRegion, popupRegion);
    }
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<FormVersionsView>();

    }
```

Here is part of Publish module

```
public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        if (_regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName(RegionNames.PopupContentRegion))
        {
            _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.PopupContentRegion].Add(typeof(Views.Publish), "Publish");
        }
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Views.Publish>();
    }
```

Inicialization of `popupWindow` is in contructor of my `MainWidowViewModel`

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        popupWindow = unityContainer.Resolve<DefaultPopup>();
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<PopupWindowClosedEvent>().Subscribe(CloseDefaultPopupWindow);
    }
```

In `MainwindowViewModel` I have OpenCommand, which should open popup window with corresponding view.

```
void ExecuteOpenCommand(string navigatePath)
    {
        if (_regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName(RegionNames.PopupContentRegion))
        {
            var view = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.PopupContentRegion].GetView(navigatePath);
            _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.PopupContentRegion].Activate(view);                
        }
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.PopupContentRegion, navigatePath);             
        popupWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

After executed this code, "PopupContentRegion" has 2 views and only one view is active, depend on parameter of this command.

I expect that popup window will not be empty and there will be the content of the corresponding view.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you create an initalize `popupWindow`?

Comment: in constructor of `MainWindowViewModel`

Comment: You need to post all relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I've added constructor of `MainWindowViewModel`. Tell me what else you need to see from my code. What are the relevant parts for you?